# JavaScript return only regex from string

Tags: javascript, regex

This might be pretty simple, but I am having a hard time with it. Consider the following code:

```
var string = 'testingT#$^%#$ESTING__--232'
string = string.match(/^\w*$/)
if (string != null)
{
    string = string.join('')
    string = string.toUpperCase()
}
$('#my-input').val(string)
```

What I want to do, is to strip all characters that aren't alphanumeric or underscore from `string`, and then transform that string to uppercase.

So far I did that, it works perfectly if I don't add any special characters, but when I add `-` or `^` to it, for example, it deletes everything from `#my-input`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in one step:

```
string = string.replace(/[^\w]/g, '').toUpperCase();
console.log(string); //=> "TESTINGTESTING__232"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z_0-9]/g,'').toUpperCase()
```

Also, do you need unicode? My regex will only match a-z, and not åÉø for example.

Answer (score 1):

You need use 'global' flag in regex and remove match restriction.

```
var str = 'testingT#$^%#$ESTING__--232';
str = str.match(/\w+/g);    
if (str !== null)
{
    str = str.join('');
    str = str.toUpperCase();
}
$('#my-input').val(str);
```